# If we can “give someone a call”, why can't we “give a phone call”?

Tags: verbs, spoken-english, collocations

According to Cambridge Dictionary a ***phone call*** (*also* phonecall) is something that you *make*, and provides the following examples

> 1. Will you excuse me? I need **to make a** phone call.
> 2. I've got a few phone calls ***to make***.

*Collins Dictionary* defines *[phone call](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phone-call)* as:

> If you ***make* a phone call**, you dial someone's phone number and speak to them by phone.
> 3. *Wait there a minute. I just have to **make** a phone call.*

However, there's also the expression “***give*** someone *a call*” which
Cambridge says:

> **give someone a call/ring**
>
> - *[Give me a call/ring](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give)* (= phone me) *when you get back from holiday.*

*[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give-somebody-a-call-buzz)* offers numerous examples and suggest that *call* can be substituted with *buzz* and in British English with either *ring* or *bell*. I don't think I've ever heard anyone say *“give somebody a bell”*, but the BBC's website [Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/features/the-english-we-speak/ep-170808#:%7E:text=%27A%20bell%27%20originates%20from%20the,give%20us%20a%20bell%27%3F) confirms that it is indeed a valid British expression.

The snippet below is taken from an English language course book called *Complete Advanced* by Cambridge Press. In this exercise, students are asked to replace the verb underlined with *give* or *make* or mark it as correct.

> [image: Questions 6 and 7]
>
> 6. In my boss's absence, I give telephone calls to customers, clean desks, and write emails.

The correct answer for Q6 is  *“I **make** telephone calls…”*. Why would “give a call to a customer” or “give telephone calls to customers” be incorrect? When we **give a call** to someone, we manually select their number and “dial” it.

---

**Is there a reason  we don't say "make someone a call” even when it involves “dialling” i.e. *making* a telephone call**? And vice-versa, if we can “give someone a call”, why can't we “give a phone call” too?

<sub>P.S Q7 is correct!</sub>

Comment: Before telephones even existed, you could [***give** him a shout*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22give+him+a+shout%22) (to get his attention, after which you might ***tell*** him something). But the process of *telephoning* someone (especially in the early years) probably seemed so much more involved and technical that you had to ***make*** it happen (set it up, whatever). And once an idiomatic usage gets established, it can endure long after the original "reason" is irrelevant and/or long forgotten.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you might be onto something there, it suspiciously looks like an answer to me. I have tried to explain it to an Italian  private student that to give a phonecall means someone has to receive it whereas making a phonecall emphasises the action. Can't say I really convinced myself.

Comment: I think your approach is at least *part* of the "explanation" (to the extent that idiomatic usages can be "explained" at all :)  ***Making*** anything (a call, a fuss, an excuse, amends,...) only requires specifying *the thing[s] made*. But ***giving*** someone a call requires specifying both direct (the call) and indirect (the recipient) objects. Hence *Please excuse me - I have to make some calls*  is fine, but it wouldn't work with *...I have to **give** some calls.* And *Please excuse me - I have to **give some people some calls*** is just a contrivance too far! :)

Comment: "To give someone a bell" is indeed used in the UK. It think Aussies use it too. As to the explanation of why we say it one way and not another, I suppose it's because these are idioms (not literal), and many idioms are fixed expressions, and you can't really mess with them, and if you do, they sound odd.

Comment: "When we give a call to someone" is generally expressed as *give someone a call. Give a customer a call*. Frankly, I think asking why we don't say "make someone a call" is just a waste of time. Like the answer below says make a phone call and give someone a call. Two different idioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of your initial reasoning is around the expression '*to make*' a phone call, which is different from '*to give*' someone a call.

'Give (someone) a call' follows the same construction as other idiomatic expressions relating to contacting someone. "*Give (someone) a knock*" means to call at their door; "*give (someone) a shout*" means to get in touch by any means. Other slang expressions for making phone calls include "*give (someone) a ring*" and "*give (someone) a buzz*".

This would suggest that "*give (someone) a call*" developed from existing idiomatic language for communication, whereas to '*make*' a call is language that developed specifically in connection with the technology of telephony. This is further evidenced by the fact that, when we use the verb *to give*, there has to be an object and a recipient either stated or implied. This language focuses on who you are contacting as much as, if not more than, the means of doing so. That isn't the case when we say we are 'making' a call - it is entirely optional whether or you not to choose to say to whom the call is being made (eg "*Excuse me while I make a call*", or "*I'm going to make a call to my parents*"). Arguably, 'making' calls focuses on the use of the phone.

There is no reason at all why you can't say "*give (someone) a phone call*" - it's just more common to say 'call'. Likewise, you can "*make a call*" without using the word 'phone'. The word is tacit, or implied.

Also, there is a difference between the way we use 'call' as a verb in connection with the telephone compared to calling at their door. Certainly in British English we would say "*I'm going to call my dad*" for a phone call, but "*I'm going to call **on** my dad*" to mean call at his door. However, in business, in-person visits to clients may be referred to as "calls" (a noun) in the same way that instances of phone contact are. This makes it more likely that someone saying "*I'm going to make some calls*" may need to qualify it by stating either *phone calls* or perhaps *house calls*. Certain contexts require specificity that others do not.

Comment: Aren't "Give me a [phone] call" and “Give someone a [phone] call” the same thing? Is there any reason why we can't say "I give telephone calls to customers"?

Comment: The word ***(tele)phone*** is generally [implicit / unstated, not explicit.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Give+me+a+call%2CGive+me+a+phone+call%2CGive+me+a+telephone+call&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes they are, and no there isn't - although the latter sounds odd... perhaps because it sounds like a job description where 'making calls' sounds more business-like.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I don't think you can, but I don't know why not. It's just not idiomatic. Not in my dialect anyway. Maybe because 'to' implies motion toward, which doesn't happen in a phone call.

Comment: I like the edit :)